# How to get multiple ajax submit get multiple input value, defined by id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to create a multiple button with multiple submit to update link so i made this

```
function updateurl(id){
    var linkurl=$('#link'+id).val();
    alert(linkurl);
}
```

and html markup:

```
<input id="link<?php echo $id; ?>" value="abc">
<input type="button" onclick="updateurl('<?php echo $id; ?>')" value="Check">
```

And of course this did not work, but i could not find out why!

NOTE

I using the above code and it does not alert when i click Check button.

I believe error is in javascript below, if i click check button, i get an alert box with 'undefined'

```
   function updateurl(id){
        var linkurl=$('#link'+id).val();
        alert(linkurl);
    }
```

because when i change it to

```
   function updateurl(id){
        alert(id);
    }
```

It works well !

and if i change above code to

```
   function updateurl(id){
        var linkurl=$('#link').val();
        alert(linkurl);
    }
```

and markup html to

```
<input id="link" value="abc">
<input type="button" onclick="updateurl('<?php echo $id; ?>')" value="Check">
```

It works too !

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please create a jsbin/jsfiddle for this so we can see what is "wrong".

Comment: Looks like your PHP variable `$id` does not have a value

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pwF4c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `$('#link'+id).val();` combo so thats why, its undefined, so you dont have a match as far as i can see.

Comment: <input id="link<?php echo $id; ?>" value="abc"> does that thing,i have to have an alert box with "abc"

Comment: I checked the fidle, you have to place the function outside your document ready  http://jsfiddle.net/pwF4c/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input id="link1" class="aa" value="abc">
<input type="button" class="bb"  value="Check">
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.bb').click(function(){
        alert($('.aa').val());
    });
</script>
```